# Using GitHub's GraphQL API, how can I tell who closed an issue or pull request?

Tags: graphql, github-api

Given an issue or pull request number, I'd like to get the following information using a single query to the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/):

- Whether it is an issue or a pull request
- The state of the issue (open, closed) or PR (open, closed, merged)
- If the issue or PR is closed, who closed it and when
- If the issue or PR was merged, who merged it and when

Using the following query, I have all of this working except for determining **who** closed the issue or PR:

```
{
  repository(owner: "Automattic", name: "wp-calypso") {
    issueOrPullRequest(number: 23226) {
      __typename
      ... on Closable {
        closed
        closedAt
        # TODO: How to get ClosedEvent { actor } ?
      }
      ... on Issue {
        issueState: state
        title
      }
      ... on PullRequest {
        prState: state
        title
        merged
        mergedAt
        mergeCommit {
          committer {
            user {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running this query using GitHub's GraphQL Explorer tool:  https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

I can see the issue or PR as a [`Closable`](https://developer.github.com/v4/interface/closable/) but I think I need to get from there to the last [`ClosedEvent`](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/closedevent/) that affected that object.  This is the part I haven't been able to figure out yet.

In GitHub's v3 REST API, determining all of this information may require 2 requests.  For a pull request that was **closed** (not **merged**), the `closed_by` field only appears when requesting the pull request **as an issue** (via the [`issues`](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) API call).  All other pull request information is available via the [`pulls`](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One roundabout (and ugly) way for getting the actor who closed the issue is as follows (inspired by this [answer](https://platform.github.community/t/get-the-assigned-and-closed-dates-of-an-issue/4101)). I'm hoping there might be a better way but here's an approach as of now.

The trick is to query for a considerable amount of events in a given timeline (if you are absolutely sure that there are no comments on an issue/PR after it is closed, you can say `timeline(last: 1)`), find the `ClosedEvent` or `MergedEvent` among them and extract the `actor`

```
{
  repository(owner: "Automattic", name: "wp-calypso") {
    issueOrPullRequest(number: 23226) {
      __typename
      ... on Closable {
        closed
        closedAt
      }
      ... on Issue {
        timeline(last: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              __typename
              ... on ClosedEvent {
                actor{
                  login
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ... on PullRequest {
        timeline(last: 100) {
          edges {
            node {
              __typename
              ... on MergedEvent {
                actor{
                  login
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `timeline` field, I think that is the connection I was missing here.  However, the suggested query would end up being extremely verbose to cover the most common possibilities, and it will still fail under certain conditions (if an issue or PR has many comments or other events after being closed or merged).  The code required to manipulate this response object is also far more complicated than just making 2 requests to the REST API.  I'm accepting this solution as correct, but I think the overall answer is "this task is not workable using the GraphQL API".

Comment: @jnylen I agree. It would be nice to have a concise way of getting this done. Also, regarding the point of the code to parse being complicated will it still not be cheaper than making 2 over the network calls? I havent benchmarked this and so I'm unsure, just a food for thought though

Comment: Trade-offs... 1 network request with a very complicated query and unknown complexity on the server side, that doesn't always work, and requires complicated processing by the client (hard to test).  Or, 2 relatively simple network requests for standard objects, with a slight bit of combining to do afterwards.

Comment: I chose 2 requests (with appropriate caching in my application).  Much simpler and more maintainable this way.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed in the behavior of both kinds of GitHub APIs here, to be honest.